# Why aren't quartz crystals' pin pitch aligned to the inch grid?

Tags: oscillator, crystal

This is most probably stupid question, but I would love hearing the story. Can not find anything relevant in the net.

The spacing between the pins of HC-49 is 4.88 mm, there're some other variations like 12.3 mm and 3.75 mm, all of them are not exact multiple of 0.1" (or even 0.01").

More to consider - the pitch is even not aligned to the metric grid...

I found it out after drawing the crystal gasket and putting it onto the crystal device on the board, being astonished to see that my assumption about 0.2" pitch being wrong.

[image]

Comment: Never assume dimensions! That's what data sheets are for... Does your PCB layout not have standard packages already defined?

Comment: Most probably I copied it from standard EAGLE library... let me check... package HC49U in crystal.lbr is having pitch og 4.826 mm, as well as HC49/S. I am looking at the libraries with version 6.6.0, but I created my own symbol by copying standard library part about 8 years ago (I am more than sure I just added central ground pad) and there is no guarantee there was no pitch mistake that time. In general crystal fits excellently into 0.2" pitched footprint (and I never insert crystal compleltely in, otherwise may have damaged the glass sealing), that's why I did not notice the issue earlier!

Comment: With the mis-pitched holes, did you find that the crystal was held in well enough to turn the board over and solder it without it falling out?

Comment: Yes! And I found it *very* useful, however did not know why it is the case. But as I said I was not inserting crystals completely; with the gasket I am going to put them totally in through the gasket, thus there will be very small distance, and, as I read in documetation, misalignment may cause damage to the glass sealing and thus render crystal defective shortly.